# Objective C equivalent for ActionScript's include statement

Tags: ios, objective-c

In case where two classes that have different class hierarchies but need to share some code, what is the best approach in ObjectiveC? In actionscript, you can do:

```
class A : B{
include "commoncode.as"
}
class C : D{
include "commoncode.as"
}
```

And then you put the common code in commoncode.as

Edit : Here is what the actionscript include statement does :
"At compile time, the compiler copies the entire contents of the file into your class, as if you had actually typed it. "

Comment: You can do that in C too (and by extension, Objective C). It's a bad idea though. Can't you put the common code in a function instead?

Comment: Not sure I understand - commoncode.as contains a bunch of functions. It is not a compilation unit, just something that gets inserted during pre-compile.

Comment: You should more precisely describe what ActionScript's include does. Otherwise it is difficult to find a matching concept for you needs in Objective-C.

Comment: @user2453876 Yes, it's the same concept in C (it's just typically used to bring in self-contained units). #import, however, is different. And as I said, you're better avoiding this. If you have a series of functions in it, use inheritance instead.

Comment: :-) cannot use inheritance - I dont own Class B and D. Cannot change them. must inherit from them. CommonCode contains a bunch of common properties (getters and setters) that are dumb and call into a common class that has the actual implementation. So you are saying i can simply do include "commoncode.m"??

Comment: Usually you'd name it with `.h` to show that it shouldn't be compiled on its own. And yes, you can. But seriously consider any other way of doing it (doing it this way makes your code harder to read, harder to debug, and less likely to play nice with intellisense). What you're doing sounds like multiple inheritance. Maybe composition is a better approach?

Comment: Thanks - I see what you are saying, and I am using composition. Class A and C have an object E. Class A and C both implement an interface that has a ton of getters and setters. Each getter and setter is a simple call to the corresponding getter and setter of the composited object E. I just dont want to repeat all this code in A and C, much rather do it in one place, which is why I need the include.

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the right answer, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In AS3, you have the ability to use 'interface' to have a Class conform to a certain set of methods. In Objective-C you have 'protocols' which essentially accomplish the same goals. However, this will only allow you to define required (or optional) methods, not implement them. Implementation would still occur in the Class itself.

If you have a class (called CommonCode) that just has helper methods, you could just include the header file in the class that needs to use the methods. For example, a MathUtils Class could look like:

***MathUtils.h***

```
CGFloat distance(CGPoint point1,CGPoint point2);
```

***MathUtils.m***

```
CGFloat distance(CGPoint point1,CGPoint point2) {
    CGFloat dx = point2.x - point1.x;
    CGFloat dy = point2.y - point1.y;
    return sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy );
};
```

When included in a Class, you would then be able to call this method like:

```
CGFloat dist = distance(myPoint1, myPoint2);
```

I should note that these are C style functions, not Objective-C. But, you could easily make the MathUtils Class static using class methods rather than instance methods.